# How to achieve localisation with NoSQL

Tags: parsing, localization, nosql

Until now, I've always used relational databases (and was quite happy indeed!). However, recently, I discovered [Parse](https://parse.com/) and found it quite nice so decided to give it a try. However, it comes with a NoSQL database. I am still trying to get my head around it. So my question is, how would you recommend achieving localisation? I could think of the following approaches, what do you think?

- Approach A: Have a single 'strings' field on the document and store all language specific data in that field. For example,

  ```
  "strings":
  {
    "en" : 
      {
        "title" : "English title"
      }
    "de" :
      {
        "title" : "Deutsch Titel"
      }
  }
  ```
- Approach B: Have multiple fields on the document, each field pointing to one language specific file. An define another document named *strings*. For example,

  ```
  "strings_en": <Pointer to a *strings* object>
  "strings_de": <Pointer to a *strings* object>

  // And here's one *strings* document
  {
    "title" : "My English title"
  }
  ```
- Approach C: Just as in a relational database schema, have a separate *strings* table with language code. Query this table/document separately and merge results
- Approach D: (NEW) Similar to Approach B, favouring many columns over two documents with the aim of keeping all relevant data in the same document.

  ```
  {
    "title_en" : "English title",
    "title_de" : "Deutsch titel",
    "description_en" : "English description",
    "description_de" : "Deutsch beschreibung"
  }
  ```

Approach A: Makes sense to me, but I don't know an easy way (in Parse framework) to send back only the relevant data to the client. It will send all strings to the client -> redundant bandwidth use

Approach B: Coming from a relational db background, I don't like the prospect of having too many columns (it can eventually have 30 different columns for 30 different languages) and also, the client can't just use object.*strings*. It always has to append the language code at the end of the field name, which is tedious (and risky too). But this approach makes most sense to me.

Approach C: I can hear you saying 'What's the point of NoSQL if you're going to adapt NoSQL to relational db design paradigm'

Approach D: Yes, you will end up with ridiculously many columns but I felt a key goal is to keep all necessary data in one document as opposed to distributing them over 1+ documents. And number of fields is not a problem at all. Hence, I'm going with this approach now.

So, how do you achieve localisation in your NoSQL db schemas?

Answer (score 2):

There was a discussion on the RavenDB forums about this very topic recently.  [See Here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/DD4lPQNKEtg/fcC0vALrxc0J)

Like most things in NoSQL, there are many different options.  One idea that came up is that in many document databases (like RavenDB), you can have string-based "semantic" keys.  These could be exploited to provide data localization.

For example, consider multiple documents working together to represent a product:

```
products/1
{
  "Price" : 10.00
{

products/1/en
{
  "Name" : "ball"
}

products/1/es
{
  "Name" : "bola"
}

products/1/fr
{
  "Name" : "balle"
}
```

The non-localizable properties are stored in `products/1` which is the main document key. But then localizable strings could go in other documents that are related by their key.

To make this work well - there is some management overhead of working with the different documents.  In RavenDB - this would be provided by a custom "bundle".  (It doesn't exist yet - I am working on it.)  Other databases may have different implementation details that might still allow this approach to be viable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added an Approach D and started using that one. I'll edit my question now. I felt NoSQL is about keeping all necessary data in one document (even if that means ending up with a lot of fields) so that's why I am trying to keep both in the same document as opposed to creating a separate document

Answer (score 0):

Ayende suggested to use somehting like

```
{
  "States": [
    {
      "Name": [
        {
          "Culture": "en",
           "Value": "Texas"
        },
        {
          "Culture": "fr", 
          "Value": "French Texas" 
        } ],
        "Abbrevation": "TX" 
    }]
}
```

Comment: Where did Ayende said this?

Comment: First link in Google http://ayende.com/blog/77825/modeling-reference-data-in-ravendb. Look down in comments.